# how to print the sum of salary of employees stored using a class in python

Tags: python, class

I have created a class to store the details of all the employees and display the same. But I have to display the sum of salary of all the employees. I am unable to do that. Can anyone help me......???

```
class Employee :
    empid = 0
    name = None
    salary = 0.0
    def getInput(self) :
        print("Enter the empid :: ", end ="")
        self.empid = input()
        print("Enter the name :: ", end ="")
        self.name = input()
        print("Enter the salary :: ", end ="")
        self.salary = input()
    def display(self) :
        print("Employee id = " + str(self.empid))
        print("Employee name = " + self.name)
        print("Employee salary = " + str(self.salary))
    def main( args) :
        e = [None] * (3)
        i = 0
        while (i < 3) :
            e[i] = Employee()
            e[i].getInput()
            i += 1
        print("**** Data Entered as below ****")
        i = 0
        while (i < 3) :
            e[i].display()
            i += 1
     
if __name__=="__main__":
    Employee.main([])
```

How to print sum of salary of employees after storing them using this.???

Comment: your class is designed very poorly, consider at least moving `main` function out of the class

Comment: What is `sumsalary()` ?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need to get `main()` out of your class. Then, you should actually add the code that calculate the sum of the salaries. `sumsalary()` isn't declared anywhere in your code, the reason that you are not getting an error, it's because the value of `i` is greater than `3`, so that part isn't reachable.

I updated your code so that it calculates the sum without creating a function.

```
class Employee :
    empid = 0
    name = None
    salary = 0.0
    def getInput(self) :
        print("Enter the empid :: ", end ="")
        self.empid = input()
        print("Enter the name :: ", end ="")
        self.name = input()
        print("Enter the salary :: ", end ="")
        self.salary = input()
    def display(self) :
        print("Employee id = " + str(self.empid))
        print("Employee name = " + self.name)
        print("Employee salary = " + str(self.salary))
    

def main(args):
        e = [None] * (3)
        i = 0
        while (i < 3) :
            e[i] = Employee()
            e[i].getInput()
            i += 1
        print("**** Data Entered as below ****")
        i = 0
        while (i < 3) :
            e[i].display()
            i += 1
            
        i=0
        sum_salary = 0
        while(i<3):
            sum_salary += int(e[i].salary)
            i += 1
        print("sum salary: " + str(sum_salary) )
            
if __name__=="__main__":
    main([])
```

Comment: And [here](https://tio.run/##fZLBboMwDIbveQorJ9hQRdtLVYnDtPWy827rFGXFjEgQUJJqqqo@O0sgBNiq@UKU/7f9xaa9mLKR212ruu5Uca3hULdVc0HcE7CRYwGMCSkMY5HGqkgA61bkCUheYwKaV1xd4sHswnlWvQWywbqUXJpV3GcpDJWsNBzIrL02ynefNVJozkpCQUdg6FteJ4DbUdJj8LuYmT3HNUD96w5w1xnrjRJCHGHNhYw8GvoUbc3vH/1V0ShgICQoLr8w2s4eMQ5KSBMJ2Z5NRA/SoAJTohf3e6BxHDI89x9zf997p7GO0Here/VX@YC/4m2LMo/GEUT31h4PW2qV60AfbMALNxz6LpgD1/CJVfMNTqLebRrDKxbg0jAjDIuUE8c0q6HLKEzIi3qPWUj1W5oTvjlrmAtNFrkWT7i/zb2QsSyjjLnFMkYHhmHLXbcmr00pyTpNU7IhT5U4IdnZ85Y8l1xVqMnGSj8) how it should look. Your code isn't really better than original and contains lot of mistakes.

Comment: @OlvinRoght You really wasted your reputation for this ? LOL. It's like we are playing for money here or something. The question was how to calculate the sum of the salaries, he didn't asked if his code was performant. If you had another solution, you could've just added another answer. *"isn't really better than original"*, It may not be in your opinion, but it does answer the question.

Comment: No, I am not the one who downvoted, but if you're asking... Your code contains dozen of mistakes and it's terrible example for ones who just started with programming, it's not about performance but using bad practices.